# Google.Apis.Urlshortener in C# giving Error JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, google-api, nuget, url-shortener, jsonreader

I want to use Google Nuget package for shortening URLs. 
I included all the required files

```
 public string shortenIt(string url)
    {       
        UrlshortenerService service = new UrlshortenerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "*************************",
            ApplicationName = "***************",
        });
        Url response = service.Url.Insert(new Url { LongUrl = url }).Execute();
        return response.Id;
    }
```

I am getting the following error on

```
  Url response = service.Url.Insert(new Url { LongUrl = url }).Execute();
```

**Error**:

```
  JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 1
```

I would be please to know the solution..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's URL shortener is no longer available, you should move to using Google's Firebase Dynamic Links.

Source: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html

Comment: is the URL shortening in Firebase Dynamic Links free as google?

Comment: I am not able to find how to use it with the free package (Spark plan). It says this extension need: blaze plan

Comment: @Shomaail - I think it will be hard to help you from the comments, please could you consider asking a new follow up question?